# How can I download Silverlight videos and convert to FLV format?

Tags: conversion, flv, silverlight

Is there any way to download Silverlight videos and convert them into FLV format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that is no way to (at least) download Silverlight videos when it is selected but not playing and later perform the conversion to FLV format.

Answer (score 0):

Get Orbitdownloader [Click Here](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/silverlight-downloader/download-videos-from-silverlight-free.htm)

Than download Format Factory converter  [From here](http://www.formatoz.com/) to convert Silver Light video to .flv extension

Comment: The Orbitdownloader can download the Silverlight video when playing but what I wish for was that it can download when it is selected but not playing.